# "A referral was returned from the server" in powershell when trying to use Remove-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, active-directory

**Intro**

I have a script that works without issue for users in the root domain. Basically what it does is it

1. Imports a csv of users
2. Grabs their distinguished name
3. Sees if their distinguished name exists in a list of distinguished names in a group
4. If  their DN is indeed in the group, remove them from the group.

**Issue**

However, I am running into issues when trying to remove users in a child domain from a group located in the root domain.

**The Error**

```
Remove-ADGroupMember : A referral was returned from the server
At U:\powershell\AD\Remove_users_from_group.ps1:16 char:9
+         Remove-ADGroupMember $groupDN -Members $user -Confirm:$false  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (CN=GroupA C=Domain,DC=com:ADGroup) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ADRe 
   ferralException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8235,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

**Code**

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "users.csv" -Header 'Username'

$group = 'GroupA'
$groupDN = Get-ADgroup 'GroupA'| Select -Property DistinguishedName

$incount = 0
$notcount = 0

$members = Get-ADGroupMember $group -Server "domain.com" | Select -Property DistinguishedName

ForEach ($Username in $csv) {
    $user = $Username.Username
    $user = Get-ADUser $user -Server "child.domain.com" | Select -Property DistinguishedName
    if ($members -like $user){
        Remove-ADGroupMember $groupDN -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Server 'domain.com'
        #Set-ADObject -Identity $groupDN -Remove @{member=$($user)} 
        write-host "Removed:" $user
        $incount++
    } Else {$notcount++}
}

Write-host "Task complete"
Write-host "Users removed from" $group ":" $incount
Write-host "Users that were not in" $group ":" $notcount
$prompt = Read-Host -Prompt "Press enter to close"
```

Answer (score 1):

A referral is returned when a DC cannot do what you want to do, but it knows who you need to talk to do what you need to do. In this case, that means it isn't connecting to the correct domain, but `Remove-ADGroupMember` isn't capable of following the referral. Since you are not specifying the `-Server` parameter for `Remove-ADGroupMember`, it's likely connecting to whatever domain you're logged into. The solution is just to use the `-Server` parameter to make it talk to the correct domain, just like you were doing with `Get-ADGroupMember`.

```
Remove-ADGroupMember $groupDN -Members $user -Confirm:$false -Server "domain.com"
```

I see another problem with your code: You are using the `-Recursive` parameter with `Get-ADGroupMember`, meaning that it will return users who are members of groups, where that group is a member of `$group`. But then you are using `Remove-ADGroupMember` to remove the user from the group as if it was a direct member of that group. `Remove-ADGroupMember` will fail for users that are not direct members.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I removed `- recursive` and added `-Server domain.com` and still had the same issue. I also tried `child.domain.com` just for fun, and no change :c Same error.  I've updated my post with the changes

Comment: Do you get the same error as an enterprise administrator?